# Unity: Simple Match 3+ in row/column Minigame

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a simple minigame for my project that requires player to match 3+ objects in a row/column to get points. Currently I'm at a loss as to why it sometimes works, and sometimes not.

Also, more often than not my script matches blocks that it shouldn't.

Basically, I'm storing all blocks in a `MinigameBlock[,]` array, then projecting it on the scene. After that every move on the scene is refflected back on an array, then the function for matching rows kicks in:

```
public void CheckForRows()
{
    var list = new List<MinigameBlock>();
    for (int y = blocksArray.GetLength(1) - 1; y >= 0; y--)
        for (int x = blocksArray.GetLength(0) - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            MinigameBlock[] r = null;
            if (blocksArray[x, y] != null)
                r = blocksArray[x, y].Check();
            if (r != null) list.AddRange(r);
        }
    foreach (var obj in list.Distinct())
        Destroy(obj.gameObject); //For now
}
```

Here's the `Check()` function of `MinigameBlock`:

```
public MinigameBlock[] Check()
{
    var t = type;
    List<MinigameBlock> blocks = new List<MinigameBlock>();
    var pos = manager.blocksArray.FindIndex(this);
    if (pos[0] > 1)
    {
        var _blocks = new List<MinigameBlock>();
        _blocks.Add(this);
        var match = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
            if (manager.blocksArray[pos[0] - i, pos[1]] != null && manager.blocksArray[pos[0] - i, pos[1]].type == t)
            {
                match++;
                _blocks.Add(manager.blocksArray[pos[0] - i, pos[1]]);
            }
            else break;
        if (match >= 3)
            for (int i = pos[0]; i < manager.blocksArray.GetLength(0); i++)
                if (manager.blocksArray[i, pos[1]] != null && manager.blocksArray[i, pos[1]].type == t)
                {
                    match++;
                    _blocks.Add(manager.blocksArray[i, pos[1]]);
                }
                else break;
        if (_blocks.Count >= 3)
            blocks.AddRange(_blocks);
    }
```

(This is only for horizontal matching for now)

Also, here is my butchered attempt at populating the board with blocks:

```
void InstantiateBlocks()
{
    var parent = GameObject.Find("Table").transform;
    int lastId = 0, sameBlock = 0;
    int _x = 0, _y = 0;
    for (int y = -2; y <= 3; y++)
    {
        for (int x = -4; x < 4; x++)
        {
            if (Random.Range(0f, 1f) < 0.8)
            {
                if (sameBlock == 0)
                    lastId = Random.Range(0, blocks.Count);
                else if (sameBlock >= Random.Range(1, 3))
                {
                    sameBlock = 1;
                    var _id = lastId;
                    while (lastId == _id)
                        lastId = Random.Range(0, blocks.Count);
                }
                else sameBlock--;
                var b = Instantiate(blocks[lastId]);
                b.transform.SetParent(parent, false);
                b.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0f);
                blocksArray[_x, _y] = b.GetComponent<MinigameBlock>();
                sameBlock++;
            }
            _x++;
        }
        _y++;
        _x = 0;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong, aside from the fact that the code needs craploads of optimization?

Comment: In the check() method add brackets {} to for loop so it loop properly.

Comment: It isn't looping properly now?

Comment: Who knows?  The brackets will let people who read your code exactly what you meant the code to do.  Do you want the code to execute both 
"if (match >= 3)" and "if (_blocks.Count >= 3)"